# How do I upload files to the server using the drf-chunked-upload library?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, file-upload, django-rest-framework

I have tried many ways to upload a file to the server, but I always get the response {"detail": "No chunk file was submitted"}. How to use this library correctly?

One of my attempts:

```
import requests

url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/chunked_upload/'

in_file = open("testfile.txt", "rb")
data = in_file.read()
response = requests.put(
    url,
    headers={
        "Content-Range": f"bytes {0}-{9}/{10}"
    },
    data={"filename": "testfile"},
    files={'file': data},
)
```

Comment: Try not to read the file and use the file handle directly.

Comment: @KlausD. Do you mean try it this way: `files={'file': in_file }`? If so, it unfortunately does not work

Comment: You must not read the file as well. And BTW "It does not work." is not a good error description.

Comment: @KlausD. I did as you said, same error `{"detail": "No chunk file was submitted"}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open a file and make repeatedly PUT requests to the server in chunks.
To complete the upload make a POST request with the file's checksum.

### Example

```
import hashlib
import os

import requests
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth

auth = HTTPBasicAuth(username='username', password='password')

file = 'prova.txt'

size = os.path.getsize(file)

hash_md5 = hashlib.md5()

CHUNK_SIZE = 100

with open(file, 'rb') as f:
    url = 'http://localhost:8000/'
    offset = 0
    for chunk in iter(lambda: f.read(CHUNK_SIZE), b''):
        hash_md5.update(chunk)
        res = requests.put(
            url,
            data={'filename': 'my_new_file'},
            files={'file': chunk},
            headers={
                'Content-Range': f'bytes {offset}-{offset + len(chunk) -1}/{size}'
            },
            auth=auth
        )
        offset = int(res.json().get('offset'))
        url = res.json().get('url')
    finalize = requests.post(url, data={'md5': hash_md5.hexdigest()}, auth=auth)
    print(finalize.status_code)
    print(finalize.json())
```

Comment: thank you very much for the answer, but there was a new error on the server when sending the file. `ValueError: Cannot use ModelSerializer with Abstract Models.` Do you know what this might be related to? I didn't change the model and view of the source library.

Comment: Hi.. maybe you are using the ChunkedUpload model from drf-chunked-upload as abstract, Check this settings: DRF_CHUNKED_UPLOAD_ABSTRACT_MODEL

Comment: that's right, I'm using a ready-made model from the library (ChunkedUpload). DRF_CHUNKED_UPLOAD_ABSTRACT_MODEL setting is set to true by default

Comment: Set to False and migrate.

Comment: Unfortunately, a new exception has appeared. `django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'chunkedupload-detail' not found. 'chunkedupload-detail' is not a valid view function or pattern name.` As far as I understand, you need to specify the path in the file urls.py for the second post request. But which one?

Comment: take a look here: https://github.com/jkeifer/drf-chunked-upload/blob/master/tests/urls.py for an example.

Comment: Thank you very much. Now everything is working